# Get renderUI to work mid way through an observeEvent

Tags: r, shiny

I have a renderUI that I need to update mid way through an observeEvent.

Basically, When I click on the load button in the below example, firstly input$Test1 needs to update with new values, then I need the renderUI to update, then I need to update the input values in this renderUI. (This usually comes from me loading a file, but this simplified version should suffice)

I have simplified this below. Basically, I need input$DynamicTwo to be filled in on the first pass - It currently only fills in once I've clicked on input$Load twice.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "navbar", 
  id = "navbar",
  tabPanel(
    "panel1", 
    selectizeInput("Test1",label="Test1: UI on panel2 depends on this",choices=c("One","Two","Three"),multiple=T,selected="One"),
    actionButton("Load","Make Test1=Two and fill in DynamicTwo with B")
  ),
  tabPanel(
    "panel2",
    uiOutput("DynamicOnTest1")
  )
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$DynamicOnTest1<- renderUI({
    lapply(input$Test1,function(x) {
      selectizeInput(paste("Dynamic",x,sep=""),paste("Dynamic",x), choices=c("A","B","C"),multiple=TRUE)
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$Load ,{
    updateSelectizeInput(session,"Test1",selected="Two")
    #somehow I need to get the renderUI to run in here, before...
    updateSelectizeInput(session,"DynamicTwo",selected="B")
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I've hit a mental brick wall here so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two workarounds to it, but depending on what you really plan to do with your app, they might be not suitable. But maybe that can help you go through your mental brick wall.

### First solution using `observe`

Create an observer for your dynamic input.

```
  observeEvent(input$Load ,{
    updateSelectizeInput(session,"Test1",selected="Two")
  })

  observe({
    input[["DynamicTwo"]]
    updateSelectizeInput(session,"DynamicTwo",selected="B")  
  })
```

### Second solution using `shinyjs::delay`

Wait for `DynamicOnTest1` to be rendered first, so we are sure that `input[["DynamicTwo"]]` exists.

```
ui <- navbarPage(
  title = "navbar", 
  id = "navbar",
  tabPanel(
    "panel1", 
    selectizeInput("Test1",label="Test1: UI on panel2 depends on this",choices=c("One","Two","Three"),multiple=T,selected="One"),
    actionButton("Load","Make Test1=Two and fill in DynamicTwo with B")
  ),
  tabPanel(
    "panel2",
    uiOutput("DynamicOnTest1")
  ),
  shinyjs::useShinyjs()
)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$DynamicOnTest1<- renderUI({
    lapply(input$Test1,function(x) {
      selectizeInput(paste("Dynamic",x,sep=""),paste("Dynamic",x), choices=c("A","B","C"),multiple=TRUE)
    })
  })

  observeEvent(input$Load ,{
    updateSelectizeInput(session,"Test1",selected="Two")
    shinyjs::delay(1000, updateSelectizeInput(session,"DynamicTwo",selected="B"))  
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hi Kluu, thanks for the help. Does Dynamic Two autopopulate with B selected in your second example? That's not currently working for me.

Comment: Yes it does, but that mostly depends on how much time the server needs to go through `updateSelectizeInput` and `renderUI`. Have you tried to increase the delay (e.g going from `1000ms` to `2000ms`)?

Comment: Ahh it works, but only if you switch to panel2 within that delay time (I tested with 5 seconds). If you leave it longer than the delay time to switch then it doesn't update.

Comment: Oh I see, that's not ideal, then there's possibly a better solution. Lemme think...

Comment: It looks like adding in `updateNavbarPage(session,"navbar",selected="panel2")` before the `shinyjs::delay()` solves this. I just can't switch back to panel1 which isn't the end of the world